# Every update of android sdk manager increases sdk folder size. Is there anything, that can be deleted?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, size

- After downloading android sdk for the first time (around january 2013)
  sdk bundle size was around 700mb (i don't remember exactly)
- At that time I ticked all the check boxes and downloaded all the packages and the size increased to approximately three times
- Then periodically I have always checked for updates and downloaded every update whenever available.
- Now I see that the SDK folder size has grown to huge big large = 73GB.
- What confuses me is, even today when I see the android SDK bundle download size, it is near 1gb and after extraction it takes around 3gb space.
- While using SDK manager i have never clicked the 'delete packages' button till today.
- Is it so that previous revision numbers are not of use and only latest shall be kept?
- What is the best practice?
- We develop applications with minimum API 7 (not android 7).
- Suggest me, is there something that I have to delete?